# How to build dexdump in Android platform-tools?

Tags: android, c++, dex, android.mk

I've cloned https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik.
Then I've introduced some changes to DexDump.cpp file and I wanted to build it with those changes but I failed.

I tried using:

```
make -f Android.mk
```

inside root directory but I get these errors:

> Android.mk:25: /libdex/Android.mk: No such file or directory
>
> Android.mk:25: /dexgen/Android.mk: No such file or directory
>
> Android.mk:25: /dexdump/Android.mk: No such file or directory
>
> Android.mk:25: /dx/Android.mk: No such file or directory
>
> Android.mk:25: /tools/Android.mk: No such file or directory

Even though all these Android.mk files exist. Also, I'm pretty sure I'm positioned in a right directory when calling 'make'.

I have very little experience with C and C++ so many of these things are completely new to me.
Did anyone here build dexdump successfully? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached to Google developer and he helped me build it. Here is his email to me:

> Start here: https://source.android.com/source/building.html
>   Once you have set up the build environment (the steps before "Build the code"), use the bash functions imported by envsetup. Don't run make, that's not how it's intended to be used for projects. Run mma. The result will be in out/host/linux-x86/bin.
>   Note that the dalvik/ dexdump will be deprecated some time soon, and the dexdump2 version inside art/ will replace it.

You can also run "mma dexdump" and it should build only dexdump. Just change the code to suit your needs in DexDump.cpp